# Pandas performance improvement over pd.apply with eval()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I'm trying to optimize my script performance via Pandas. I'm running into a roadblock where I need to apply a large number of filters to a DataFrame and store a few totals from the results.

Currently the fastest way I can make this happen is running a For Loop on the list of filters (as strings) and using eval() to calculate the totals:

```
for filter_str in filter_list:
    data_filtered = data[eval(filter_str)]
    avg_change = data_filtered['NewChangePerc'].mean()
```

Here's my attempt at using pd.apply() to speed this up because I can't think of a vectorized way to make it happen (the filters are in a DataFrame this time instead of a list):

```
def applying(x):
    f = data[eval(x)]
    avg_change = f['NewChangePerc'].mean()

filter_df.processed.apply(applying)
```

The main goal is to simply make it as fast as possible. What I don't understand is why a For Loop is faster than pd.apply(). It's about twice as fast.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE
Here's more specifics about what I'm trying to accomplish:

Take a data set of roughly 67 columns and 2500 rows.

```
       Code                              Name    ...         Price NewChangePerc
0   JOHNS33                  Johnson, Matthew    ...          0.93      0.388060
1   QUEST01                   Questlove, Inc.    ...         18.07      0.346498
2   773NI01                 773 Entertainment    ...          1.74      0.338462
3   CLOVE03                  Cloverfield, Sam    ...         21.38      0.276418
4   KITET08                       Kite Teal 6    ...          0.38      0.225806
```

Then take a list of filters.

```
['Price > 5.0', 'NewChangePerc < .02']
```

Apply each filter to the data and calculate certain values, such as the average NewChangePerc.

For example, when applying 'Price > 5.0', the average NewChangePerc would be ~0.31.

Now grow that list of filters to a length of about 1,000, and it starts to take some time to run. I need to cut that time down as much as possible. I've run out of ideas and can't find any solutions beyond what I've listed above, but they're just too slow (~0.86s for 50 filters with the For Loop; ~1.65s for 50 filters with pd.apply()). Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Because `.apply` is just a for loop, it's not meant to be fast, rather, it's a method of last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. That makes sense. Although I would think it would be roughly the same speed then. And is there a better method that I can use in this situation?

Comment: You are going to need to provide way more information if you want and sort of solid advice. You should probably provide example data, inputs, expected outputs...

Comment: Well, in the second case, you are iterating over a `pd.Series`, I believe, which is slower than iterating over a Python `list`

Comment: Good to know. I was trying to keep it concise so that it wasn't overwhelming. Let me see what I can add without making it too much.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/) is the best guide.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually where I got the idea to throw the filters into a DataFrame! I'm just stuck at how to to get past the .apply() step if it's even possible, given my situation.